# Text overlaps on mat-icon-button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create navbar with Angular's mat-toolbar. I've added icons with mat-icon. When i tried to add labels for them, the text overlaps with the icons.
[screen of the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vmHZ.png)
html:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="warn">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <img src="/assets/img/logo.png" width="150">
        <span class="example-fill-remaining-space"></span>
        <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
            <span>home</span>
        </button>

        <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>history</mat-icon>
            <span>home</span>
        </button>

        <span>
            <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
                <span>language</span>
                <button mat-menu-item>ENGLISH</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>POLISH</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>ITALIAN</button>
            </mat-menu>
            <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
                <mat-icon>language</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

css:

```css
.example-fill-remaining-space {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.mat-icon {
    font-size: 25px;
    height: auto !important;
}

.icon-text {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want the text to display?

Comment: For example next to the button icon. Also I would like the text to works as button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using `mat-icon-button`. `mat-icon-button` is a circular button with a transparent background, meant to contain an icon. If you want to add text to this button, use `mat-button` instead.

```html
<button mat-button class="toolbar-button">
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
    <span>home</span>
</button>

<button mat-button class="toolbar-button">
    <mat-icon>history</mat-icon>
    <span>home</span>
</button>
```

`mat-button` has `padding: 0 16px;` by default which will stretch out the buttons in `mat-toolbar`. To avoid this we need to override it.

```css
.toolbar-button {
    padding: 0;
}
```